# What is the difference between async.map from async library and Promise.map from bluebird?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, bluebird, async.js

I explain myself:

What I want to do is using async/await with one of those library (async or bluebird).

I don't understand why this works well:

```
const promises = Promise.map (someArray, async item => {                
      const result = await getSomething(item);
      return {...item, ...result}
});

const promisesResults = await Promise.all(promises);
```

But the same with async.map doesn't. It returns me `undefined`.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: *But the same with async.map doesn't.* - it can't be the same because it's different library. What code exactly do you try?

Comment: `const promises = async.map (someArray, async item => {                
      const result = await getSomething(item);
      return {...item, ...interview}
});`

Answer (score 1):

`async` is legacy library that solved same problems as promises before the propagation of promise pattern and the emergence of native promises. `async` *library* is callback-based and is unaware of promises and `async` *functions*, which are syntactic sugar for ES6 promises.

The snippet works because `Promise.all` expects an array of promises:

```
Promise.all(promises);
```

And an array of promises is provided with array `map` with `async` function callback:

```
someArray.map(async item => { ... })
```

This won't work with `async` library because it's supposed to work with callback-based iteratee function and is unaware of promises that `async` function returns.

Since ES6 promises lack some advanced features from `async` library, they can be augmented with Bluebird API or [promise ponyfills](https://github.com/sindresorhus/promise-fun#packages).

Comment: I understand! So if I want to use async/await and Promise.all it is better to use bluebird library right ?

Comment: Yes, you don't need `async` lib when you work with promises. You may not need Bluebird too if `Promise.all` is all you need. `someArray.map` code you originally posted would work with ES6 promises alone. You may take a look at promise ponyfills which offer most things that Bluebird does to not depend on the whole Bluebird library.

Comment: I use a lot `Promise.all` in my project and I read that to avoid creating an array of promises every time I can easily use` Promise.map` from bluebird. I am gonna take look at `ponyfills`. And tell me what about performance ? async or bluebird ?

Comment: If you don't need temp variable you can skip it, it's as simple as `Promise.all(someArray.map(async item => ... ))`. Pure Bluebird promise chain is faster than pure native promise chain (may change in future) but most performance improvements are discarded since `async` uses native promises any way. I'd say the performance is not a reason to choose Bluebird here. As for `async` library, I didn't measure but promises are fast enough to not bother with premature optimization.